# bitcoin-qt keeps on quitting with "failed to read block"

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, client

I just wanted to install bitcoin-qt on another machine (all others are working fine) but I cannot seem to retrieve the block chain using bitcoin-qt 0.8.6-beta (as downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.8.6/bitcoin-0.8.6-win32-setup.exe/download).

I'm running bitcoin-qt (started as as administrator) on Windows 8 using a 3G data connection. After downloading a few thousand blocks the software keeps on quitting with the error "failed to read block". When I restart the software it fetches another thounsand blocks and quits with the same error soon.

Even a full reinstall (I additionally deleted the whole data directory in %APPDATA\Bitcoin) doesn's seem to help. Starting bitcoin-qt with "-reindex" didn't help either. I checked the hd-drive for errors but didn't find any.

What am I dong wrong?

Comment: As *administrator*?? Why do people do that?

Comment: Usually I'm not doing this. I just wanted to prevent answers pointing out that rights problems could be the reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start bitcoin-qt in a new command prompt with the flag **-reindex** after you make sure your 3G provider doesn't block your downloads after a certain threshold.

Comment: I already tried to reindex. My provider doesn't block traffic (I can tell this as I'm working on the same connection meanwhile - without putting too much load on it).

Comment: Since you have other computers working fine, one thing you could try is to copy the blocks' files from a working client to the one that throws that exception. You will have to delete in source and then copy the block files, which can be found under: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory. You will need to rescan and wait until the new blocks get verified, just like as they had just been received by the network.

Comment: OK, then I'll copy the block files from another machine when I return and get access to it. I just thought I set up bitcoin "quickly" (usually it takes about a night to be done) but in this case it didn't seem to work. Strange behaviour nevertheless...